# Как создать arp ответ scapy?

Tags: python, сеть, scapy

на scapy можно создать arp запрос

```
pkt = Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')/ARP(pdst='192.168.43.1')
```

В wireshark примерно такая картина:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хотел бы узнать как создать пакет который будет не делать запрос а отвечать на запрос:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда создаёшь пакет, нужно параметр op поменять с дефолтого значения (1) на 2.

1 - запрос

2 - ответ

`packet = scapy.ARP(op=2)` а дальше другие параметры: pdst, hwdst, psrc, какие тебе надо